# Insert into value as generate row with different minutes

Tags: postgresql

I try backup and restore using WAL-E/WAL-G.

I can backup and restore.

But i want check recovery_target_time.

During recovery, by default WAL-E will attempt to pull and restore all WAL segments available. If you wish to restore to a specific POINT IN TIME than specify.

```
# restore to 4:38PM on 3/6/2012
recovery_target_time = '2012-03-06 16:38:00'
```

I think need generate value every minute long time and Insert into table.

Found insert events with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
INSERT INTO events (ts,description) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'disc full');
```

Found insert SELECT NOW()

```
INSERT INTO indexing_table(created_at) SELECT NOW() FROM generate_series(1,100);
```

This is no answer :(

How build table?

```
         created_at           
-------------------------------
2019-02-13 14:16:20.799219+03
2019-02-13 14:17:20.799219+03
2019-02-13 14:18:20.799219+03
2019-02-13 14:19:20.799219+03
```

or

```
    created_at           
-------------------
2019-02-13 14:16:20
2019-02-13 14:17:20
2019-02-13 14:18:20
2019-02-13 14:19:20
```

Need generate row with different minutes.

Any help would be appreciated in creating these tables!
Thanks!

Comment: Another option to generate WAL would be to use `pgbench` and let it run for a long time.

Comment: Not Generate WAL. Need generate row with different minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your question is, but if you are confused that all rows have the same timestamp value, this is because `now()` and `current_timestamp` return the time at the start of the transaction.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the “current” time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp

And then:

> `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command.

So if I understood your question correctly, you probably want to use `clock_timestamp()` rather than `now()`

---

Another option is to use `generate_series()` to generate timestamps:

```
INSERT INTO indexing_table(created_at) 
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 
                     timestamp '2019-03-31 00:00:00', 
                     interval '1 minute') ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this code to cron: */1 * * * * postgres psql -U postgres -d test1 -c "INSERT INTO indexing_table(created_at) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"